# How to change Table data source record

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, nsdictionary

My table view data continuously changes because it gets data from the web. Now problem is some time my table view misses some of the records when user is scrolling the view and data arrived from net. So i want to now how can i change the table data source values when user is interacting or scrolling the table view.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem caused by reusing table view cells in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

if you use:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

You could try:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
```